# Cpp initialize std::map in header

Tags: c++, header, initialization

I want to initialize a std::map in `my_cpp.h` header file:

```
std::map<std::string, double> my_map;
my_map["name1"] = 0;
my_map["name2"] = 0;
```

But there was a compile error showed up:

```
error: ‘my_map’ does not name a type
```

Can someone explain why this not work for a C++ newbie?
Thanks

Comment: `std::map<std::string, double> my_map{{"name1", 0}, {"name2", 0}};`

Comment: Answering your question: your code doesn't work because statements must be within a body of some function. Only declarations can be present outside any function.

Comment: Thanks all the help above and the below, seems this is a very beginner and stupid question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize a map in a `.h` file like that. Those assignment statements need to be inside a function/method instead.

Otherwise, initialize the map directly in its declaration, eg

```
std::map<std::string, double> my_map = {
    {"name1", 0.0},
    {"name2", 0.0}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The header file is just a declaration, or initialize the map directly .
You can modify your code like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

const std::map<std::string, double> my_map = {
  { "name1", 0 },
  { "name2", 0 }
};
```

Comment: The other answered first so I have him the as the resolution. But still appreciate for the help.